# Creating parameterized Spring bean configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring

Is it possible to have a parameterized bean template where in we can just fill in the place holders or pass arguments to tell what bean to refer to or what value to set?

```
<bean id='baseBean' abstract='true' argument='arg1'>
    <property...>
    .
    .
    <property name="tableName" value='arg1'>
</bean>
<bean id="derived1" parent='baseBean(table1)' >
    .
    .
</bean>
<bean id="derived2" parent='baseBean(table2)' >

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not pass this way parameter to class, 
 work as a parameter name as tablename in your class for which you want to create a bean. i.e.

```
<bean id="ds"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/SBS_SL_MERGE" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

in above example DriverManagerDataSource class having variable named as driverClassName,url,username,password you just passing value of those for parameter for refrence of that class....

If you want to refer this bean you can refer simply by passing bean id.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="ds" /> 

   </bean>
```

now in above case there is a variable in DataSourceTransactionManager  named as dataSource which required object of DataSourceTransactionManager with all default set values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and define your bean id's in a properties file and control it from there.Like we use to configure database properties.

Comment: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is simply for  pulls values from a properties file into bean definitions...

Comment: Thats the trick, you can dynamically give bean id's and pass refrences on the go